# UIdocumentPickerViewController customization

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-drive, uidocumentpickervc

Apple provide iCloud Drive in iOS 8.
For review documents I use `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. But I can not understand how to create folder with custom icon such as this one: (Documents by...)

[image]

Comment: Late to the party. Take a look at the comments to this question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351589/how-do-you-customize-the-icons-within-a-uidocumentpickerviewcontroller