# Create folder in iCloud and sync documents by my own app

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, icloud, document

I need to create a folder in iCloud.Then sync PDF documents with the folder.Just like the Documents APP.How to create the folder and how to sync?
[UIdocumentPickerViewController customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119009/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller-customization/34449579#34449579)
[documents app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmk3q.png)

Comment: https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/implementing-ios-8-document-pickers/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497213/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller-all-files-grayed-out