# How do you customize the icons within a UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am currently trying to customize my `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and I am having trouble changing the colors of the icons that represent the files within the documents directory. They are all blue and I want to turn them orange. Would I have to create my own icons and insert them?

Comment: Essentially yes - you need to create a `QLThumbnailProvider` extension to dynamically build the icons. Check out this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/5244-document-based-apps-tutorial-getting-started which focuses on `UIDocumentBrowserViewController` but same family of functionality. The last section deals with creating the `QLThumbnailProvider` extension ( disclosure: I wrote this tutorial  )

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Warren. It seems like your tutorial uses the framework `Markup` to achieve this. Is there any way to do it without using that framework? It seems like using that framework adds a lot of extensions and extra structure to the project that I don't want to include.

Comment: The framework is directly related to THAT project only to allow the plugin and the app to share code. At a general level you need  to build your own `QLThumbnailProvider` extension that relates to your own code and document/file content. You may or may not wish to use a framework structure to achieve this.

Comment: Oh okay I see. I'll give that a shot then.